# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
grades = {
    ("DD1", 1) : 45,
    ("DD1", 2) : 75,
    ("DD1", 3) : 25,
    ("DD1", 4) : 65,

    ("DD2", 1) : 85,
    ("DD2", 2) : 40,
    ("DD2", 3) : 70,
    ("DD2", 4) : 80,
    }
def listGrades(dataBase, group):
    list_of_score = []
    for key, value in dataBase.items():
            if key[0] == group:
                list_of_score.append(value)
    return list_of_score

dataBase = input("Which database?")
group = input("which group?")

print(listGrades(dataBase, group))
```

Upon debugging, I get this:

```
Which database?grades
which group?DD1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DuckyGoh\Desktop\1003\tt3.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(listGrades(dataBase, group))
  File "C:\Users\DuckyGoh\Desktop\1003\tt3.py", line 43, in listGrades
    for key, value in dataBase.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Can someone educate me on my mistake and how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you enter 'grades' when asked by `input` and hope that it would be replaced by the content of the `grades` dict?

Comment: I would like to make use of an input to allow the user to select which dict he/she would like to retrieve values from(grades, grades...), is there a way to do so? @Norrius

Comment: I would like to have multiple dictionaries(currently only have one dict **grades**), eventually the program will have, perhaps, grades1, grades2, grades3. Upon input from the user, it would return values from the respective dict. @ThierryLathuille

Comment: are u using python3?

Comment: yes, 3.7.4 to be exact. @arunp9294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    def input(__prompt: Any = ...) -> str: ...
else:
    def input(__prompt: Any = ...) -> Any: ...
    def intern(__string: str) -> str: ...
```

From python 3 onwards input is accepted as string. For python2, the above could accept dataBase as object available in globals.

```
grades = {
    ("DD1", 1) : 45,
    ("DD1", 2) : 75,
    ("DD1", 3) : 25,
    ("DD1", 4) : 65,

    ("DD2", 1) : 85,
    ("DD2", 2) : 40,
    ("DD2", 3) : 70,
    ("DD2", 4) : 80,
}

dataBases = {
    'grades': grades
}

def listGrades(dataBase, group):
    list_of_score = []
    for key, value in dataBase.items():
        if key[0] == group:
            list_of_score.append(value)
    return list_of_score

dataBase = input("Which database?")
group = input("which group?")

dataBase = dataBases.get(dataBase, {})

print(listGrades(dataBase, group))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, @arunp9294 that's very interesting to know. lets say I have another dict "grades2", it seems like I have to add 'grades2': grades2 to dataBases dict. Is this the only way allow user to select dict?

Comment: You can also use `dataBase = globals().get(dataBase, {})` but i wouldn't recomment it

Comment: I see, thanks for your input @arunp9294. I will look into your solution myself! Thanks!